# gcc fails with "undefined reference" in Cygwin, but the reference exists in a linked library

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I've built and installed libmarpa in Cygwin with the end result being in `/usr/local/lib/libmarpa.a`.

I have a simple file:

```
#include "libmarpa/dist/marpa.h"

int main() {
  return marpa_check_version(8, 3, 0);
}
```

But the linker fails to find `marpa_check_version`:

```
$ gcc test.cc -L/usr/local/lib -lmarpa
/tmp/ccdYM1vV.o:test.cc:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `marpa_check_version(int, int, int)'
/tmp/ccdYM1vV.o:test.cc:(.text+0x1e): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `marpa_check_version(int, int, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But the symbol exists as a function:

```
$ nm /usr/local/lib/libmarpa.a | grep marpa_check_version
0000000000002780 T marpa_check_version
```

So what's happening here? Is there a problem trying to do this within Cygwin, or am I invoking gcc incorrectly?

Comment: Could you try 1) rename tst.cc in tst.c 2) compile with this command line: gcc tst.c /usr/local/lib/libmarpa.a

Comment: Few things you can try checking. First, ensure the lib you're linking in indeed the same platform as your build-target (x86 vs x64 or vice-versa obviously won't play nice together). Second, try passing your lib and lib-locations prior to your source file. Third, possibly a mangled name? (gcc is specifically calling out a missing function with three `int` params, so perhaps someone neglected an `extern "C"` somewhere critical or the lib was intended for C-clients only?

Comment: @WhozCraig @ouah I think you're both right, thanks. I was originally trying to compile C++, then switched to gcc thinking that would result in compiling as C, not realizing that the filename ending determined how the file was processed.

Compiling "test.c" works, as does compiling "test.cc" and adding `extern "C" { }`  around the header file.

Comment: You can use `-x` to tell gcc to ignore the extension and use a specific language: `gcc -x c test.cc -L/usr/local/lib -lmarpa`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This symbol:

```
undefined reference to `marpa_check_version(int, int, int)'
```

is C++ [mangled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling). This symbol is not:

```
0000000000002780 T marpa_check_version
```

The problem is that `marpa.h` developers did not expect their code to be used by `C++`, and have not put in proper guards for this. You can fix the problem like so:

```
extern "C" {
#include "libmarpa/dist/marpa.h"
}

int main() { ...as before ...
```

P.S. You should also change your command line to use `g++` instead of `gcc`. Contrary to popular belief, they are *not* the same thing.

Comment: I was actually *trying* to use gcc, thinking it would simplify my problem. But I didn't realize gcc would still treat "test.cc" as a C++ file. So, renaming the file to "test.c" works, as does using the extern "C" linkage with g++ (which is what I wanted).

Comment: thanks for the hint. using `g++` instead of `gcc` cleaned up many undefined reference errors.